# how can i install WebSphere MQ on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ibm-mq

i'm trying to install  WebSphere MQ in my Ubuntu with rpm command but i'm getting the following error:

```
 Use of rpm to install MQSeriesRuntime on the Ubuntu distribution is no longer supported
     Installation terminated
```

and all the installations exit with 255 code status.
does anyone know with witch command I need to replace rpm please.

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ are you attempting to install?

Comment: i'm installing version 9.1.2

Comment: IBM provides Ubuntu packages now.   Have you tried those?

Comment: Check out this blog https://colinpaice.blog/2019/03/25/i-think-the-ibm-instructions-for-install-mq-on-ubuntu-gets-6-10/

Comment: You have choice of dpkg (see https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2019/03/18/mq-installation-and-uninstallation-on-ubuntu-using-debian-packages/) or apt (see https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2019/03/25/mq-installation-uninstallation-on-ubuntu-using-debian-packages-using-apt-command/)

Comment: Feeling a bit left out in posting links - Other than the blog links there is also a tutorial for installing IBM MQ for Developers on Ubuntu - https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/mq-connect-to-queue-manager/#ubuntu

Comment: @chughts - sorry not to have shared that link - I had never seen it before. Need to publiscise it a bit more? Also, rather interestingly, the two blog posts I posted links to appear to have disappeared which is very odd.